# add and substract time in php

Tags: php, time

i have time in the format 04:00 PM so how can i add or substract time in that... in such a way that when i substract AM and PM are also maintained...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('04:00 PM');
```

Comment: Is it adding/ subtracting anything?

Comment: It converts your `PM/AM` time format to a timestamp, which allows you to do anything - convert it to other format, extract any part (using `date()` for eample), etc. Also you can add to that timestamp any value (for example 60 minutes: `$timestamp + 3600`).

Comment: how about adding those in your answer. will not make it more effective?